# Python Two Dimensional Bin Packing

Tags: python, list, function, grid

Alright so I am trying to make a program that prompts for a square bin dimension using a list of lists to fill this list of lists with squared blocks. It also prompts for a text file for example: blockList.txt:

```
3 1 2 1 3
```

I have a function that splits that up into a list and tries to fill in the space of the lists using the First Fit descending algorithm. The problem is is that the function only fills the highest valued item in the list and then stops and prints the grid. Can someone help me figure out why it isn't looping correctly? All help would be much appreciated

Here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ac55a8fcb350d0992a4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on python syntax, but it seems you called your placement() function in your pack() function before you defined your placement() function. That could be messing you up.

Comment: That is to say, place your pack function before your placement function and see if that helps any.

Comment: Also, your program does not seem to go to the next element in your list of blocks if it fails to place a previous one.